# How to remove/hide action links cluttering under specific plugins' names

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, headers, debug

Some plugins place various links under their name on the primary column on the plugin page. So we end up with something like:

```
Home Page | Support Forums | Documentation | Upgrade to Pro Edition | Donate | Settings | Activate | Delete
```

In an effort to keep just the standard links `Settings | Activate | Delete` we use in our custom `01_plugin.php` the following code:

```
 global $pagenow; 
    if( $pagenow == 'plugins.php' ) {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
        .visible .proupgrade, 
        .visible .docs, 
        .visible .forum, 
        .visible .jetpack-home, 
        .visible .support 
            {display: none ; 
            } 
          </style>'; 
    }
```

When debugging, for some reason, it gives a PHP Warning:

```
PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /wp-content/plugins/01-plugin/01_plugin.php:282) in /wp-content/plugins/wp-miniaudioplayer/miniAudioPlayer.php on line 231
```

Can someone point us to the right direction? Which hook should we use?
Is there another way to achieve our goal?

> #### EDIT

To better understand where these links are located, please have a look at the screenshot:

[image: primary-bloated]

As you can see **they bloat the primary column out of proportion**, using/wasting precious space, that could be otherwise awarded to the secondary column.
Note: **The primary column does not wrap**. The secondary does.

Comment: Are you using a hook?

Comment: @Nath. No. Not really. The above code is all that is added. Have you any suggestions/answers?

Comment: So if your not using a hook how are you adding this code?

Comment: I cannot figure out where to hook it. Could you provide a solution? Even better could one use a **_non-css_** solution?

Comment: Check out https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts/ to add your own css. I can't really provide better than that at the moment as I am still not sure what you are trying to do really.

Comment: I am aware of the linked page which bears no content. The above mentioned code gives us the desired result with just the standard action links `Settings | Deactivate | Edit | Delete` **once the plugins are activated**. We also though get the warning when the [specific plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-miniaudioplayer/) is also activated. We cannot find out why so we try to **load the css only at the plugins screen** hoping the warning will go away. To simplify the question: How can we make the above css fire for only the plugins page OR achieve the same result without css.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I first thought you meant the meta rows, but I then updated my answer for the actions rows.  @marikamitsos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right approach. You will want to use the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) hook:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_239302_hide_action_links' );
function wpse_239302_hide_action_links() {
    global $pagenow; 
    if ( $pagenow == 'plugins.php' ) {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .visible .proupgrade,
            .visible .docs,
            .visible .forum,
            .visible .jetpack-home,
            .visible .support { display: none; } 
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Two newbie questions though. 1. Is this what we should do whenever targeting admin pages using css (create a new action with a custom function and use `admin_enqueue_scripts`)? 2. Let's say we need to target other admin screens e.g. for the profile screen `.user-admin-color-wrap` to hide the Admin color Scheme as well as for the dashboard use ` #wp-version-message` to hide the wordpress version for _just the subscribers_. Do we need to create a new action for every single screen? Can we combine them and how? Could you please update your answer with the relevant code?

Comment: @marikamitsos To answer your first question, it depends. Also, it's best to ask a separate question since the original question have been solved. This way, I can give you a better and more detailed answer, with an example.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the reply for my second question. But I thought of giving it a shot anyway. You could [elaborate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290231/1527780) though on the "_depends_" part, since '_[providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300846/1527780)_".

Comment: @marikamitsos Again, it depends because I rather show you a couple of answers in order to achieve the same results with more details in my reasoning. Unfortunately the amount of characters I can type in these comments won't be enough or legible.

Comment: Of course "_the amount of characters I can type in these comments won't be enough or legible_". It is not what I suggest here. On the other hand it is quite common for someone to [edit](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/98535/1) an answer in order to provide a [really useful](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/98535/117311) reply.

Comment: to style admin dashboard for different roles, then you have to append user-role into body-class. (Use [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66834/how-to-target-with-css-admin-elements-according-to-user-role-level))

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
add_action('admin_footer', function () {
    if( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] == 'plugins.php' ) {
    echo '<style type="text/css">.visible .proupgrade,  .visible .docs, .visible .forum, .visible .jetpack-home, .visible .support {display: none ; }   </style>'; 
    }
});
```

to style admin dashboard for different roles, then you have to append user-role into body-class (Use [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66834/how-to-target-with-css-admin-elements-according-to-user-role-level)) .

Comment: Your code works great as well. Could you please explain though couple of points? Why should one use `admin_footer` and not `admin_enqueue_scripts`? Is it because it is css which should/could be loading in the footer? Are there any differences/benefits or just personal preference? Since it is just a line would it make any difference inlining it and if so how? Do you also have an opinion concerning [my comment](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/239302/how-to-remove-hide-action-links-cluttering-under-specific-plugins-names#comment359460_241011) on the other answer?

Comment: it is just personal preference and easier to hook into `admin_footer`, however, for scripts and styles, more recommended way is `admin_enqueue_scripts` (but that is used primarily for major scripts and styles, like jquery,bootstrap and etc), in your case, the custom solution i have given, will work well too. I will make another answer for the other question you wanted for subscribers and etc..

Comment: I've commented you there too, about user-roles.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Could you please edit your answer and incorporate it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: @marikamitsos ok, done.

Comment: Hoping I am not too picky I was also referring to "_for scripts and styles, more recommended way is admin_enqueue_scripts (but that is used primarily for major scripts and styles, like jquery,bootstrap and etc), in your case, the custom solution i have given, will work well too._" Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We might also try to change the layout via CSS, differently than hiding it.

Here's an example where we target the row actions of that plugin and display each action in a seperate line:

```
tr.active[data-slug="all-in-one-seo-pack"] .row-actions.visible span{
    display: block;
}
```

Note that we target only the action rows when the plugin is active:

[image: active]

else it's like this:

[image: deactive]

Comment: Sorry. As you can see from the original post I refer to `.visible .jetpack-home, .visible .support` as well. "_All In One SEO Pack_" just happens to be in the example screenshot. As for the "_tried to remove the `settings` action link via the `plugin_action_links` filter, but that didn't work_" part I had looked into that and I think it is because there is no named span class given to it, but only a number 0 or 1 hijacking the positions. Other plugins do that as well. So ideally one should not target (if possible) the name (_Upgrade to Pro_) and not the class (_proupgrade_)

Comment: Your second update is very interesting! So interesting, I don't understand why is it not included in the core for the whole plugins page.

Comment: In general we should avoid removing those extra links (I therefore removed that part from my answer), because we never know when we need them and theycan be important for that plugin ;-) Yes I agree with you that, this is a bug that should be fixed. You should consider filing a [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/), if no-one has reported this before. @marikamitsos