# Change the layout of action links under the plugin names

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

Some plugins place various links under their name on the plugins page. To display these each action links for a specific plugin in a seperate line I followed [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/241011/25187) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/241071/25187) answers, but my code doesn't work. What I did wrong?

I use WordPress 4.9.8 with a child Twenty Seventeen theme.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_239302_hide_action_links' );
function wpse_239302_hide_action_links() {
    global $pagenow; 
    if ( $pagenow == 'plugins.php' ) {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            tr.active[data-slug="super-socializer"] .row-actions.visible span .1,
            tr.active[data-slug="super-socializer"] .row-actions.visible span .2  { display: block; }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title says "hide", but your CSS is `display: block;` not `display: none;` - why?

Comment: @kero I'm sorry, it's my fault. Now is OK?

Comment: Ok, so you want to display something specific (for your own plugin) in that area? Can you show, what you want to display and how it is currently shown?

Comment: @kero I want just what is shown here, for a third party plugin: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/241071/25187

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution by moving links in discussion from the first column to the second column of plugin admin page with these two functions:

```
/** Remove action links from the Super Socializer plugin first column **/
const PLUGIN_SLUG = "super-socializer/super_socializer.php";
add_filter("plugin_action_links_" . PLUGIN_SLUG, function ($actions, $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context) {

    unset($actions[1]); // remove link "Add-Ons"
    unset($actions[2]); // remove link "Support Documentation"

    return $actions;

}, 10, 4);

/** Add action links to the Super Socializer plugin second column **/
add_filter( 'plugin_row_meta', 'custom_plugin_row_meta', 10, 2 );
function custom_plugin_row_meta( $links, $file ) {

    if( strpos( $file, 'super_socializer.php' ) !== false ) {
        $new_links = array(
            'addons'    => '<a href="' . esc_url( 'https://www.heateor.com/add-ons' ) . '" target="_blank" aria-label="' . 
                esc_attr__( 'Add-Ons', 'domain' ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Add-Ons', 'domain' ) . '</a>', // add link "Add-Ons"
            'support'   => '<a href="' . esc_url( 'https://www.heateor.com/add-ons' ) . '" target="_blank" aria-label="' . 
                esc_attr__( 'Support Documentation', 'domain' ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Support Documentation', 'domain' ) . '</a>' // add link "Support Documentation"
        );

        $links = array_merge( $links, $new_links );
    }

    return $links;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can customise these links with this filter :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugin_action_links_plugin_file/

try that :

```
const PLUGIN_SLUG = "super-socializer/super_socializer.php";


add_filter("plugin_action_links_" . PLUGIN_SLUG, function (array $actions, string $plugin_file, array $plugin_data, string $context) {

    unset($actions[1]); // remove link "Add-Ons"
    unset($actions[2]); // remove link "Support Documentation"

    return $actions;

}, 10, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you! Good solution! 
P.S. I only removed the 'array', 'string', 'array', 'string' words from the function.

Comment: it's type declaration of the parameters https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: Tested again. Something is wrong with these type declarations. I have this error: *Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to {closure}() must be an instance of string, string given in /home/.../twentyseventeen-child/functions.php on line 31*. Without them is OK.