# Custom CSS In Admin Only For Certain Roles

Tags: admin, css, user-roles

I'm looking to apply custom CSS in the admin only for a certain user role, "Contributor" to be exact.

Everything I try either seems to have no effect, or produces a 500 error.

What I've tried has in the main been loosely based around this:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_css');

function custom_admin_css( ){

global $user;

if (isset($user->roles)  && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {

    if( $user->roles[0] == 'administrator' ) {
        //Do something
    } elseif ( $user->roles[0] == 'editor' ) {
        //Do something
    } elseif ( $user->roles[0] == 'contributor') {
        echo '<style> CSS </style>';
    } else {
        //Do something
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you `edit` your question ( using the link above ) to add in what you've tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to target with css, admin elements according to user role level?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66834/how-to-target-with-css-admin-elements-according-to-user-role-level)

Comment: @CalvT Ok, I'll rememnber that for the next time.

Comment: @JHoffmann although actually, in this case, I guess you were correct in flagging it, as I don't think that answer will ever be resolved looking at the date! Unfortunately it doesn't resolve my question. I guess I wrote in haste - sorry!

Comment: With the answer from that question you can output the user role to the body class. This way you dont have to output the CSS rules conditionally. Instead you target the user role with rules like this: `.role-editor #targetElement { display:none }`

Comment: @JHoffmann That's a good suggestion to add the role to the body class, please add that as an answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Upon request I will write an answer using a function from a suggested answer for the similar question: [How to target with css, admin elements according to user role level?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66834/how-to-target-with-css-admin-elements-according-to-user-role-level).

This function will output classes to the body element for all roles of the current user in the form `role-XXXXX`

```
function wpa66834_role_admin_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $current_user;
    foreach( $current_user->roles as $role )
        $classes .= ' role-' . $role;
    return trim( $classes );
}
add_filter( 'admin_body_class', 'wpa66834_role_admin_body_class' );
```

Now the roles can be targeted with css rules like:

```
#targetElement { 
    display: none; 
}
.role-editor #targetElement { 
    display: visible; 
}
```

These CSS rules don't have to be output conditionally. They can be placed for example in any CSS file which is included via [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) action:

```
function wp245372_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-admin-css', 'path/to/file.css', array(), 0.1);
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp245372_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function wpse245372_admin_user_css() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
       // Your Admin Stuff
    } elseif ( in_array( 'editor', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
       // Your Editor Stuff
    } elseif ( in_array( 'contributor', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
       echo '<style> CSS </style>';
    } else {
       // What Everyone Else Gets
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse245372_admin_user_css' );
```

Comment: Adding this to my `functions.php` causes my admin to turn into a blank page (basically no html, white page)

Comment: go to your wordpress installation, in the root you will find wp-config.php file. open it in your editor and search for wp_debug, and turn it to "true" you will see the error. please copy the error and paste it here.

Comment: @CalvT you should consider developing in a way that you can display or log the errors. See e.g. [debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) in the Codex. There was a PHP error in the above snippet, that I fixed. Note there's also the [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style)