# Change css for certain user roles

Tags: css, users

I am trying to do a #tribe_events_event_options{display:none;} for all the author users on my site. I don't want them to be able to set an event to featured, and I thought the simplest way was to not display the box.

Is there an easy way to target user groups for custom css?
I've made a author.css file in the child theme folder.

I found this post, but It did not do it for me.
[Custom CSS In Admin Only For Certain Roles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/245372/custom-css-in-admin-only-for-certain-roles)

```
function wpa66834_role_admin_body_class( $classes ) {
global $current_user;
foreach( $current_user->roles as $role )
    $classes .= ' role-' . $role;
return trim( $classes );
}
add_filter( 'admin_body_class', 'wpa66834_role_admin_body_class' );
```

Writing css like: example

```
.role-editor #main-header {display:none;}
```

But the css is not affected. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it in the frontend or in wp-admin area?

Comment: Have you tried to !important to the css? .role-editor #main-header {display:none !important ;}

Comment: @mukto90 it's in the wp-admin area. I am trying to disable the "feature event" option in the The Events Calendar for authors as the editor should be the only one to make events featured.
BenB I have tried "!important". The css seem to work for frontend, but not for the admin panel/events in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct maybe your selector is wrong? can you post the body html of your page that is outputed?

Comment: The code didn't work for me for some reason. I changed it to:

`add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes )
{
    if( is_user_logged_in() )
    {       
        $classes = array_merge( 
            (array) $classes,
            array_map( 
                function( $class )
                {
                    return 'role-' . $class;    // Here we prepend the 'role-' string
                }, 
                (array) wp_get_current_user()->roles 
            )
        );
    }
    return $classes;
} );`

That helped, and now I can target user roles, but not admin panel

Comment: @Blomshit the body_class filter only applies to front end, you have to use admin_body_class to target the backend. If you do a var_dump($classes) what is outputted to the screen?